# Borders in my CSS/HTML table

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I'm having an issue with a class project. I have a table set up, and there is a series of images that are supposed to form to make a background image. On said image, the table has borders.

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image: Current Table]

However, I need to have a square border around each of the dates of the calendar. So there should be a 1px border around each individual dates like one around the Taiwan Acrobats spot. But rather I'm getting the border around the images.

This is my style rule currently:

```
table.calendar {
border: 1px solid black;
border-spacing: 5px;
font-size: 8px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 40px;
width: 650px;

background-image: url(topleft.jpg), url(topright.jpg), url(bottomleft.jpg), url(bottomright.jpg),
                    url(top.jpg), url(left.jpg), url(right.jpg), url(bottom.jpg);

background-position: left top, right top, left bottom, right bottom, left top, left top, right top, left bottom;

background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y, repeat-x;
}
```

And this is the table:

```
        <table class="calendar">
        <caption>Events in Feburary at the CCC</caption>

        <colgroup>
            <col class="weekdays" span="5" />
            <col class="weekends" span="2" />
        </colgroup>

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>26</th>
            <th>27</th>
            <th>28</th>
            <th>29</th>
            <th>30</th>
            <th>31</th>
            <th>1
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Taiwan Acrobats</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$16/$24/$36</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                        <dd>1 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$8</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Joey Gallway</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$16/$24/$36</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>West Side Story</dt>
                        <dd>7 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$24/$36/$64</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>8
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>West Side Story</dt>
                        <dd>7 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$24/$36/$64</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>9
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                        <dd>1 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$8</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>10
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Jazz Masters</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$18/$24/$32</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>11</th>
            <th>12</th>
            <th>13
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Harlem Choir</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$18/$24/$32</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>14
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Chamberlain Symphony</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$18/$24/$32</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>15
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Edwin Drood</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$24/$36/$44</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>16
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                        <dd>1 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$8</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>17</th>
            <th>18</th>
            <th>19
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>The Yearling</dt>
                        <dd>7 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$8/$14/$18</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>20</th>
            <th>21
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>An Ellington Tribute</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$24/$32/$48</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>22
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Othello</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$18/$28/$42</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>23
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                        <dd>1 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$8</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>24</th>
            <th>25
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Madtown Jugglers</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$12/$16/$20</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>26</th>
            <th>27</th>
            <th>28
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Ralph Williams</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$32/$48/$64</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
            <th>1
                <dl>
                    <div>
                        <dt>Othello</dt>
                        <dd>8 pm</dd>
                        <dd>$18/$28/$42</dd>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go! Firstly each day should be a `<td>` **not** `<th>`. `<th>` should only be used for the headings Monday through Sunday.

**UPDATE** - Have a fiddle - [Fiddle link!](http://jsfiddle.net/SM6gF/2/)

1. Remove the background off the table
2. Wrap the table in a div with a class of `calendar`
3. Apply the background to the div and give the div some padding the same height as the background image

HTML

```
<div class="calendar">
    <table>
        <!-- (Remove class from table) -->
        <!-- This is the contents of the table -->
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.calendar {
    background: #CCC; /* This is where your background image should go */
    padding: 20px 0 0; /* same height as the background image */
}
.calendar table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #FFF; 
}
.calendar th, .calendar td {
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: The change to <td> definitely helped improved formatting. However; the CSS didn't. When I did that it took it and seperated it again, with it being each individual box but with an image for each one, where the image should be fully complete like in my image, just with the border on each individual "date" in the calender.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. It is a little difficult to understand your exact problem but by wrapping the table in a `div` and applying the background image to the top of that `div` you should have your answer.

Comment: Looking over the question, they asked for this to happen within the same style rule (instead of splitting it), but I cant find a way that would make that possible. Perhaps there was an issue with my professors instructions as this has given me the output I needed to have.

Comment: Actually. Try applying the background image in this fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/SM6gF/3/) Instructions in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers on this, but I'll throw in my 2 cents just in case.

I usually accomplish this with the following CSS.

```
/* Put a border on the top and right of the table */
table {border:solid black;border-width:1px 1px 0 0;}
/* And a border on the bottom and left of each cell */
table th, table td {border:solid black;border-width:0 0 1px 1px;}
```

The result is a border around every cell.